# how fill values of a dataframe based on some criteria without a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a hard time to understand how to fill a dataframe with specific values based on criteria without using for loops. Imagine the following example: I have a dataframe with First Name, Last Name, Education Level and Score. And I have another dataframe that has some of the people mentioned in the 1st dataframe but not the score column. For example the following

```
df2

A                       B                       C 
Alex                   Student                  Due
George                 Teacher                  Due
Helen                  Student                  Overdue
Maria                  Teacher                  Overdue
```

What I want to do now is to change the 'Score' column of df1 based on the following criteria:

We look at df2 and

- If the occupation in B is Student and the value in C is Due then make the Score in df1 to be 3
- If the occupation in B is Teacher and the value in C is Due then make the Score in df1 to be 5
- If the occupation in B is Student and the value in C is Overdue then make the Score in df1 to be 2
- If the occupation in B is Teacher and the value in C is Overue then make the Score in df1 to be 1

I know how to do it with for loops and if since it is very simple to be honest, but I am a bit confused how to take advantage of pandas and do it without for loops(since we want to avoid using for loops etc in Python).
My issue is, I know how to filter in pandas but I do not know how to filter AND insert a value in the cell. For example the filtering part I can do it like this

```
((df2[df2['B'] = 'Student') & (df2[df2['C'] = 'Due'))
```

but I do not know how to change the value of df1 based on this filtering of df2

Comment: I think need left join.

Comment: You can definitely use left join or merge or something that appears in SQL. But in your scenario, simple loc with conditional statements is enough: `df1.loc[(df2["B"] == "Student") & (df2["C"] == "Due"), "Score"] = 3`